# Can one StringBuilder be used for constructing multiple strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I'm trying to create a certain amount of long Strings. Should I create a new StringBuilder for each new String or can one create multiple?

I need to create 4 strings s1, s2, s3, s4. Can they all be created as separate strings by one StringBuilder, or do I have to create a new StringBuilder for each s?

Comment: What will be contained these `String`s?

Comment: `List<StringBuilder>`?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you [edit] your question and post some sample data? Do you want one `StringBuilder` instance to contain several strings? Do you need a collection of strings?

Comment: I would just use a new StringBuilder for each String to be constructed. This makes it more obvious what is happening when looking at the code in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a single StringBuilder can be used to build multiple independent Strings

Comment: Your answer is correct, but would benefit from an example.

Comment: Thought the same. But the question also would ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Can one StringBuilder be used for constructing multiple strings in
>   Java?

You can reuse the same reference of a `StringBuilder` to construct as many strings as you want but every new string will overwrite the old string in it. `StringBuilder` is not a container class. You need a [container class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) to store multiple instances of `String`. Given below is an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringBuilder sb;
        List<StringBuilder> list = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();

        sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");
        list.add(sb);

        sb = new StringBuilder("World");
        list.add(sb);

        System.out.println(sb);// Only the last value sb is constructed with
        System.out.println(list);// All the values added to list
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
World
[Hello, World]
```

Note that you can concatenate the strings to form a single string but they won't be differentiable. Even if you manage to differentiate them by putting some kind of separators between them, it will be very difficult and error-prone to process them.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this answer wrong then? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160840/13132043

Comment: Of course you can reuse a StringBuilder to create multiple strings. It just doesn‘t hold the different strings at the same time. But that’s rarely needed and would in general just be a waste of memory.

Comment: @Axel - Thanks for the comment. I've rephrased my statement to make it clearer.

Comment: @JJKam - Any update? Did it answer your question? Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: @ Arvind Kumar Avinash thank you very much, yes it did.